# Ring homomorphism into $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there injective ring homomorphisms

$$\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x(x-1)(x-2)\rangle\to \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}?$$

Can it be a surjection as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x(x-1)(x-2)) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$: see the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: The homomorphism is given by?

Comment: The homomorphism is the product of the projection maps, e.g. one of which is $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x(x-1)(x-2)) \to \mathbb{C}[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb{C}$